# Why does Apache HttpClient 4.5 log HTTP(s) traffic so poorly ? How to make it verbose?

Tags: logging, gradle, apache-httpclient-4.x

I added command-line arguments to my (Python + Gradle) build script:

```
gradle_command = [
            self._gradle,
            '--debug',
            '--stacktrace',
            '--continue',
            '-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog',  # Noqa
            '-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true',
            '-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http=DEBUG',
            '-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire=DEBUG',  # Noqa
            '-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.impl.conn=DEBUG',  # Noqa
            '-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.impl.client=DEBUG',  # Noqa
            '-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.client=DEBUG',  # Noqa
            '-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.commons.httpclient=DEBUG',  # Noqa
        ]
```

according to instructions here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging

but all that I'm getting is

```
[org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager] Get connection for route {s}->https://my_host.my_domain:443
[org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to my_host.my_domain:443
[org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: default
[org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
[org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
[org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
[org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Sending request: POST /upload HTTP/1.1
[org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
[org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager] Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@35b8469b
```

Why my http logs are so poor? I don't see headers nor body, how can I encrease verbosity?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like apache DEBUG logging doesn't work at all in my build system. I tried removing all those -D properties and build logs were the same. May be something is wrong I don't know what.